# PyWinAuto: How to find Google Meet chrome tab?

Tags: python, windows, pywinauto

I'm using Windows 10, and I want to be able to have a Python script mute the mic on a Google Meet Chrome tab when the focus is on another window. I assume the best way to do this is to first change focus to the Google Meet tab, and then to pass in the Ctrl+D mute shortcut.

If necessary, we can assume that my Google Meet is always the selected tab in one of several Chrome tab clusters. But if there's a solution that will work even when Google Meet isn't the selected tab in its tab cluster, that's even better!

Note: I specifically want to mute Google Meet through its interface, rather than disable the mic on the system level.

---

Edit: to be clear, I suspect this can be done with `pywinauto`, in which case my question reduces to:

**How can I use `pywinauto` to find my Google Meet chrome tab**, so that I can then send the Ctrl+D shortcut to that tab? (Note that I have multiple tab clusters open, and each cluster of course contains multiple tabs.)

Comment: if it runs in Chrome then maybe you should write Chrome extension in JavaScript. OR find extension which already do it. I found [Meet Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/meet-extension/dghkhbmpagbapkadlehcicngkldfieln) but it mutes mic when you start meeting.

Comment: with Python it would  have to run loop which every few milliseconds get all windows check recognize which window has Meet, check if it changed focus (it would need to remeber state from previous checking) and then remeber which windows is focused, focus Meet, mute, set focus on previous window. But I don't use Windows to test it :)

Comment: @VasilyRyabov any thoughts?